# PDAL: Couldn't create filter stage of type 'filters.voxelgrid'

Tags: lidar, point-cloud, pdal

I have the following PDAL pipeline:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Pipeline version="1.0">
    <Writer type="writers.pgpointcloud">
        <Option name="spatialreference">EPSG:28355</Option>
        <Option name="connection">dbname='lidardb' user='lidar' host='localhost' 
            port='5432' password='123'</Option>
        <Option name="table">test</Option>
        <Option name="srid">928355</Option>
        <Filter type="filters.voxelgrid">
            <Option name="leaf_x">1.0</Option>
            <Option name="leaf_y">1.0</Option>
            <Option name="leaf_z">1.0</Option>
        <Reader type="readers.las">
            <Option name="filename">run1.las</Option>
            <Option name="spatialreference">EPSG:28355</Option>
        </Reader>
        </Filter>
    </Writer>
</Pipeline>
```

I do

```
>: pdal pipeline downsample_pipelineLAS.xml
```

and i get an error

```
PDAL: Couldn't create filter stage of type 'filters.voxelgrid'.
```

Following is the output of pdal --drivers:

```
>: pdal --drivers

========================= ======================================================================================================================================
Name                      Description
========================= ======================================================================================================================================
filters.chipper           Organize points into spatially contiguous, squarish, and non-overlapping chips.  
filters.colorization      Fetch and assign RGB color information from a GDAL-readable datasource.  
filters.crop              Filter points inside or outside a bounding box or a polygon if PDAL was built with GEOS support.  
filters.decimation        Rank decimation filter. Keep every Nth point  
filters.ferry             Copy date from one dimension to another.  
filters.merge             Merge data from two different readers into a single stream.  
filters.mortonorder       Morton or z-order sorting of points. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve for more detail.  
filters.range             Pass only points given a dimension/range.  
filters.reprojection      Reproject data using GDAL from one coordinate system to another.  
filters.sort              Sort data based on a given dimension.  
filters.splitter          Split data based on a X/Y box length.  
filters.stats             Compute statistics about each dimension (mean, min, max, etc.)  
filters.transformation    Transform each point using a 4x4 transformation matrix  
readers.bpf               "Binary Point Format" (BPF) reader support. BPF is a simple DoD and research format that is used by some sensor and processing 
                          chains.  
readers.faux              Faux Reader  
readers.gdal              Read GDAL rasters as point clouds.  
readers.ilvis2            ILVIS2 Reader  
readers.las               ASPRS LAS 1.0 - 1.4 read support. LASzip support is also enabled through this driver if LASzip was found during compilation.  
readers.optech            Optech reader support.  
readers.pgpointcloud      Read data from pgpointcloud format. "query" option needs to be a SQL statment selecting the data.  
readers.ply               Read ply files.  
readers.qfit              QFIT Reader  
readers.sbet              SBET Reader  
readers.terrasolid        TerraSolid Reader  
readers.tindex            TileIndex Reader  
writers.bpf               "Binary Point Format" (BPF) writer support. BPF is a simple DoD and research format that is used by some sensor and processing 
                          chains.  
writers.derivative        Derivative writer  
writers.las               ASPRS LAS 1.0 - 1.4 writer. LASzip support is also available if enabled at compile-time. Note that LAZ does not provide LAS 1.4 
                          support at this time.  
writers.null              Null writer. Provides a sink for points in a pipeline. It's the same as sending pipeline output to /dev/null.  
writers.pgpointcloud      Write points to PostgreSQL pgpointcloud output  
writers.ply               ply writer  
writers.sbet              SBET Writer  
writers.text              Text Writer  
========================= ======================================================================================================================================
```

I don't see filters.voxelgrid.

```
>: pdal --version
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pdal 1.1.0 (git-version: Release)
```

Can someone please help me figure out what am i missing or doing wrong?

I am on Mac OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.3(15D21).

Answer (score 4):

The `filters.voxelgrid` filter requires PCL support, which it doesn't appear you have linked. On OSX, Homebrew PCL (1.7.2) should be sufficient. See [my configuration script](https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/blob/master/cmake/examples/hobu-config.sh) for hints on how to have CMake use it.

Another easy way to get going with PDAL is to use Docker. It contains a fully-featured PDAL build. The PDAL Docker `latest` image based on last stable release branch is available on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/pdal/pdal/). There's also the [Quickstart](https://www.pdal.io/quickstart.html), which should allow you to bootstrap the basics on your way to doing more advanced things.

Comment: Thanks very much. After much rambling with VTK, PCL 1.7+ is installed and PDAL installation is underway now.

Comment: PDAL is installed but i still am not able to execute the pdal pipeline. 

>: pdal pipeline downsample_pipelineLAS.xml 
PDAL: Couldn't create filter stage of type 'filters.voxelgrid'.

Comment: Looks like both Docker links are 404.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that BUILD_PLUGIN_PCL is ON in CMakeCache.txt.  The PDAL build should tell you that the plugin was built: `* PCL (required version >= 1.7) , Point Cloud Library , <http://pointclouds.org>`

Comment: Please expand on your answer a bit. It's unclear on how this helps answer the question.